# no such module 'Alamofire' but in Podfile

Tags: cocoapods, alamofire

I have adopted a Swift project from about 6 months ago and am getting the error:

[image]

It's probably not an Alamofire issue as changing the order with SwiftlyJSON causes me to get a No such module 'SwiftlyJSON' error.

I have Product -> Clean'd it and rebuilt but nothing seems to work. Here's a copy of the Podfile.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, "9.3"
use_frameworks!

target 'TatterTwo' do
  # pod 'pop', '~> 1.0'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
  pod 'KeychainAccess'
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'MBProgressHUD'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON','3.0.0'
  # pod 'Timberjack', '~> 0.0'
end
```

I am sure I am using the .xcworkspace rather than .xcodeproj

Comment: Did you pod install? Also, maybe the search paths are messed up.

Comment: yeah, I pod install'd, will look into search paths but shouldn't cocoapods be managing that. it seems like it would be better if it threw an error for not being able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there might be different reasons behind this error

First, try to stop the build and start again. If this doesn't work then
Open your Podfile, that is supposed to be located inside of the project folder. [Podfile configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBGXg.png). Make sure your target matches the project name. If you did any modification then go to terminal locate the project folder and run sudo pod update, it should give you an output "Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total pod installed". After this restart your xcode file. Oh yeah and the last make sure you are opening .xcworkspace instead of xcodeproj

Comment: Could you post your code from `Podfile configuration` through edit this answer?

Comment: Again, please rename the target name according to your Project's Name:               # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

  target 'rainyshinycloudy' do
    
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'

end

Answer (score 0):

- Reinstall Alamofire manually, and restart Xcode.
- Make sure you check "No" on the project file for ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES

It took ages for me to get it to work.